# Android cannot find xml items

Tags: android, xml

I'm creating an android app with a button, and my xml looks like this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/start"
    android:text="Start"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Then I want to get the Button in my main class, but I can't.

```
Button start;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
    start = findViewById(R.id.start);
}
```

But when I do this, the application won't run because of an error with this line:

```
start = findViewById(R.id.start);
```

But I most definitely identified the Button. Can anyone explain why this isn't working?

Comment: Welcome to SO! You've got a well-written question so +1 for that. But please include errors/exceptions/logcat output with your post when applicable in the future. I believe you have the answer now from @ThalluimPig but you could still add the error message to your post to help future users with the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

The method `findViewById()` returns a `View`. You need to cast it as a `Button`.

```
start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
```

Comment: Thanks for adding the explanation and not just code. The community as a whole appreciates that +1 :)